# Get all the webpage resources from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do I write a background script code for getting all webpage resources, say youtube.com, and store it in local storage or cache or in memory, and use the data to set the dom content of the tab later.

I tried using fetch and set the content from fetch response. But I can only set the html content, no images or scripsts or stylesheet aren't loaded with fetch and so cant be set..

```
       //background script
    
            console.log("Background script loaded.");
    
    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((tab) => {
      chrome.tabs.get(tab.tabId, (currentTabData) => {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: currentTabData.id },
          files: ['contentScript.js']
        });
      });
      console.log("Content script injected");
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    
        fetch('https://www.youtube.com')
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(data => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { html: data });
            console.log("message sent")
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
    
      });
    
    
    });
    //content script
 console.log("Content script loaded.");

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Message received: " + message);
    if (message.html) {
      console.log("Inside if");
      document.body.innerHTML = message.html;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Use performance.getEntries() in the content script and [send the data](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background script.

Comment: @Yogi Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the code. In fetch, I convert response to text for getting html, I've also tried to convert it into blob and sending the blob to content script and setting, but that also results the same proble, ie most page resources like images and stuff missing

Comment: I think what we're missing isn't "what" you're trying to do, but... why? What's the point of fetching a 3rd party page to display it?